# Any recommendations about publishing an app on the App Store?

Tags: flutter, app-store

I'm learning flutter as a hobby, and I would like to publish an app. Although I've never published an app made with flutter, I've published a game made in Godot on the Google Play store, so I think publishing an app should be quite easy and straight forward. On the other hand, I've heard that publishing an app on the App Store is quite a different story, so I would like to ask if anybody has any experience with it, especially:

- the cost (as I've heard it is quite expensive)
- is there really a bigger chance that your app won't be approved
- how long does it usually take to get your app approved
- this is dumb, I know, but can you even publish something on the App Store when you don't have Mac
- any other thoughts or recommendations about publishing an app on the App Store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, you can make a release apk build with Android Studio (Flutter plugin installed). But for publishing app to AppStore, you need to use Xcode.

1. The Apple Developer Program annual fee is 99 USD and the Apple Developer Enterprise Program annual fee is 299 USD.
2. Apple likes to reject apps like advertising and etc. It has many restrictions.
3. iOS app takes about 7 days even Android takes 2 days.
4. You can use VMware with macOS and Xcode installed. Then try to publish without Mac.
5. Apple requires archived source code so I don't think it is possible without Xcode.